# WalletConnectionError: Unexpected error at StandardWalletAdapter._StandardWalletAdapter_connect

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, react

I am creating an app where I need to connect my wallet with Phantom for Solana.
Here is the public repo [link](https://github.com/DivyanshChaudhary17/wallet-adapter-issue-repo) for the code where I am getting this (WalletConnectionError: Unexpected error at StandardWalletAdapter._StandardWalletAdapter_connect) error in the console and not able to connect to wallet it was working fine a few days ago I don't know what happened suddenly, could you please verify the code is there something wrong in my code for Solana-adapter-react implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your repo and ran the code it's working fine from my end!

[image]

[image]

Make sure you have successfully installed a phantom wallet or extension. And tried to disconnect all the connected Apps into the phantom wallet and retry to connect.

Comment: Yes now it is working fine the day i posted i was facing this issue i am not sure the reason for the issue but i have consoled error from walletprovider on error event